# Need help with validation of the design of a capacitance sensor array for soil moisture measurement

Tags: sensor, measurement, capacitance, parasitic-capacitance, calculation

### Product Description

The device is a soil moisture sensing and analysis device that uses capacitance sensing technology to help manage soil moisture in your garden. One probe set at the bottom of the device and a second probe set just under the soil line, allow the device to measure soil moisture across the full vertical profile of the soil. Analysis of the data determines if the soil is over-saturated, optimally-saturated, wilting, or dry.

Green, yellow and red, instantly recognized symbols for good, bad and in-between serve as the interface of the device. These colors are used to indicate four discrete levels of soil moisture, and a low battery warning.  The device is powered by three 4.5 V battery packs for a total of 13.5 V, which will (when the development board is replaced with its Microchip) power the device for the entire growing season.

### Schematic Comments

- The dashed lines indicate shielded cable.
- Any and all other comments on the schematic.

[image]

### Sensor Design

Capacitive sensing is a technology, based on capacitive coupling, that can detect and measure anything that is conductive or has a dielectric constant different from air.  Dielectric sensors measure the charge-storing capacity of the soil. This charge-storage approach is much more effective than a resistance approach. The ideal dielectric sensor electrical circuit is one that simply acts to polarize water molecules between two electrodes.

The parallel fingers (GND-sensor) topology works under the principle of fringing capacitance. High sensitivity along the z-axis of the sensors enables this topology to be implemented in liquid level sensing applications. The electric field lines are more dominant near the edges between the sensor and ground plates. The sensitivity of the sensors increases as sensor size increases (non-linearly). A shield on the backside of the main sensor and GND electrode provides directivity towards the soil.

[image]

[image]

Multiple sensor and ground electrodes can be alternated to have a central ground or sensor symmetry, as shown in Figure 6-3. A central ground is required for a wide directivity along the width of the electrodes and gives the widest response. A central sensor electrode is required for high directivity along the width of the electrodes and provides the sharpest response. The comb configuration, as shown in Figure 6-4, is comprised of both of these variants and very effective for wide and high directivity.

### Spin the Comb Design Around a Cylinder

This is my spin on the comb configuration. what I have to accomplish, with your help, is the validation of the sensor design and form.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Starting with the equation for capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor:

$$C=\frac{\varepsilon_r\times \varepsilon_0 \times A}{d}$$

Where:

- \$A\$ is the area of the two plates (in meters)
- \$\varepsilon_r\$ is the dielectric constant of the material between the plates (cultivated soil is 15)
- \$\varepsilon_0\$ is the permittivity of free space (8.85 x 10-12 F/m)
- \$d\$ is the separation between the plates (in meters)

Distance is the most obvious factor that needs to be reworked for my application. Given my cylindrical parallel fingers topology, how can I calculate capacitance?

### Datasheets

[Voltage Regulator](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/13756fd-2953646.pdf)
[Voltage Reference](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/adr440_441_443_444_445-1529927.pdf)
[Development Board](https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/datasheets/ABX00028-datasheet.pdf?_gl=1*a7qwtn*_ga*NTM0NjA1NDgwLjE2NjE5Nzc5Mzc.*_ga_NEXN8H46L5*MTY3ODA2MzQyMC42OS4xLjE2NzgwNjM0ODcuMC4wLjA.)
[Capacitance to Digital Converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/fdc1004-q1.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1678061241696&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F)
[Tri-Color LED](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/26/apem_03162018_Q8_Series_HMI_2018-1313762.pdf)

### References

*[Basics of Capacitive Sensing and Applications](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa927a/snoa927a.pdf?ts=1678062962366&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fduckduckgo.com%252F)*
*[Common Inductive and Capacitive Sensing Applications](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slya048b/slya048b.pdf?ts=1678063044892&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fduckduckgo.com%252F)*

Comment: This might be an unpopular opinion, but, I find carefully calculating capacitance in these 3-dimensional situations to be almost useless.  You might get within an order of magnitude or two, I guess. Better to build and test prototypes.

Comment: I did something similar to this a few years ago.  My prototypes/proof-of-concepts for the sensor were nothing more than cut pieces of aluminum foil, tape, and cling-wrap.

Comment: The parallel plate  capacitor formula explicitly ignores fringing fields. Your design, if I understand correctly, relies entirely on fringing fields. So it's a rather poor fit. This could be done with FEA accurately or do as e.d. suggests and make a mock-up.

Comment: A cylindrical sensor shape may have advantages in some system arrangements however for sensing moisture in a pot of soil it may be better to have a wider sensor coverage that averages over a wider section of soil. A single rod shaped probe would sense from a minimal area and would likely be an area that water easily flows down from the surface (along the probe's length). A flat probe utilizing several interlocking pads and located on both sides of the probe's surface may be a better choice.

Comment: As for the rest of the design: Three sets of three AAA's will yield 13.5V, not 14.5V. The resistor set used for what is likely the low battery check does not require such low value resistors or such accuracy, this just wastes battery power. That coupled with a switcher supply and an Arduino board will likely make for a shortened growing season, or for two or more replacements of all 9 batteries. With only 5 I/O lines an Arduino is a lot of over-kill for a simple system, a single 8 pin processor of the same family would easily accomplish the same and at a much lower power usage.

Comment: @Nedd That's one reason that I have the Arduino labeled Development Board. It will be replaced in production versions of the device.

Comment: @Nedd As I understand the field should extended away from the body about 2.5 cm. The configuration I am proposing features four separate sensing fields, two on the front and two on the back.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I am producing a prototype and as part of that process will mockup just the sensor for testing. I would love to find an equation for fringing fields. What is FEA?

Comment: @PStechPaul In answer to lots of your input, I have a new post.

Comment: FEA = Finite Element Analysis- a numerical method rather than a single formula per se. The idea is to create a mesh with many elements and compute the field in each element using first principles (Maxwell's equations) and assumptions that the element is sufficiently small. Similar methods are used (obviously with different equations) for structural analysis- to show deformation and stress throughout a complex part with forces applied. There are software products for this sort of thing like COMSOL, but I think in the end you're going to have to validate the results with a rough mock-up anyway.

Comment: If you can reduce the problem to a 2D problem the mesh can be made much finer with given resources. With many real problems the mesh can't be of constant element size and it has to be much finer in critical areas and coarser in non-critical areas to keep from running out of resources. This  is a pretty simple problem so that's probably not an issue.

Comment: For the FDC1004 sensor chip the datasheet recommends the supply pins be bypassed with a 0.1uf and a 1.0uf cap, you currently have just a 0.1uF, (see section 10). The datasheet also lists that the excitation signal has a 1.2 V average DC, so you may need to deal with that, perhaps a cap in series is needed to reduce any possible electrolysis action. In any case you might even consider a gold flash of the sensor plates to minimize surface oxidation.

Comment: @TimCerka it seems like youre trying to power your arduino with a voltage reference, this will not work. Voltage references are not used to power devices, they are used - as the name suggests - e.g. in opamp circuits where you need an exact reference. If youre trying to remove the switching noise from the buck converter you need a linear regulator

Comment: You know that the cost of all those batteries will be dominate the cost of the overall system.  Why use so many?  Why create a high voltage when the whole thing could work on a much lower voltage

Comment: @user69795 Thanks for driving me to figure out if mAh add up in series. They do not.

Comment: @TimCerka Are you still looking for a review of your schematics? The current version in the OP is still very sketchy and a lot of the suggestion above have not been implemented. For instance, cascading a switching regulator with a linear regulator to generate a 5V source off 13.5V is not necessary and will lead to lower voltage than you expect (5V minus the LDO dropout voltage). The suggestion of reducing the number of batteries is a must in my opinion too, or parallelization for longer runtime.

Comment: At least the power supply is rubbish, as others said already. You did not include any hints so far. Improve your question, to make it more "inspiring" to hunt the bounty ;-)

Comment: @eeintech I am redesigning the entire power supply. The device will now run on 7.2 V. Is cascading a switching regulator with a linear regulator still a problem at 7.2 V?

Comment: @TimCerka Definitely. How much current will you be drawing from your battery? If it's a low number don't even bother with the switching regulator and route the battery input straight to the 5V LDO, and in turn feed the 3.3V LDO with 5V input.

Comment: @eeintech I should be drawing about 30 mA. That’s pretty low isn’t it?

Comment: @TimCerka Yes that's really low, you don't need that switching regulator, just make sure the 5V LDO can take up to 8V input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to give the answer to @user69795, @eeintech and @datenheim. The fact that my power supply was rubbish is the most important thing I learned from this post. I now believe that I can edit and have a workable circuit. I will be back with another version soon. Thanks you all for your input.

> You know that the cost of all those batteries will be dominate the
> cost of the overall system. Why use so many? Why create a high voltage
> when the whole thing could work on a much lower voltage –  user69795
> Mar 13 at 22:34
>
> Are you still looking for a review of your schematics? The current
> version in the OP is still very sketchy and a lot of the suggestion
> above have not been implemented. For instance, cascading a switching
> regulator with a linear regulator to generate a 5V source off 13.5V is
> not necessary and will lead to lower voltage than you expect (5V minus
> the LDO dropout voltage). The suggestion of reducing the number of
> batteries is a must in my opinion too, or parallelization for longer
> runtime. –  eeintech Mar 14 at 16:17
>
> At least the power supply is rubbish, as others said already. You did
> not include any hints so far. Improve your question, to make it more
> "inspiring" to hunt the bounty ;-) –  datenheim Mar 14 at 21:41